# jQuery and JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, replace

I want to change the JavaScript function

```
function changediv(div1, div2) {
   div1.obj.innerHTML = div2.obj.innerHTML;
}
```

by something like this

```
function changediv(div1,div2) {
   $('#div1').html() = $('#div2').html();
}
```

to take advantage of jQuery. Can you help me with the correct syntax? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are those divs being submitted to the function?  As HTML Objects?  IDs?  Something else?

Comment: Hi Benjam. The divs are submitted as IDs.

Comment: Rocket, div1.obj.innerHTML is the content of <div id="div1">...</div>.

Answer (score 4):

```
function changediv(div1,div2) {
   $(div1.obj).html($(div2.obj).html());
}
```

In your 1st example, I'm assuming `div1.obj` is your DOMElement.  If not, you'll need to fix the selector yourself, but to set the `innerHTML` in jQuery you do:

```
$('sel').html('str');
```

Comment: This alternative is better for me because I can continue to use the function changediv. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

something like

```
var html_dev1 = $('#div1').html();
$('#div2').html(html_dev1);
```

Comment: The function is passed args `div1` and `div2`. There's no evidence that the actual ids of the divs are these values. That's why the selector should be $(div1) not $('#div1')

Answer (score 0):

this will replace the value of div1 to be like div2

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#div1').html($('#div2').html());
 });
```